# Unity AnimatorStateInfo.normalizedTime === 1.0f, is it the end of the first loop or start of the second loop?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

In Unity the `Animator` component has a function called `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo`. It returns a `AnimatorStateInfo` object which has a `normalizedTime` field.

This field is a float value where the integer part indicates the number of the loop the animator is currently playing the clip. The float part indicates the normalized time within this clip (`0.0f` is the start and `1.0f` is the end, I assume). For example, any value between 0.0 and 1.0 means the first loop is played, between 1.0 and 2.0 the second loop, and so on.

My question is now what is the situation when `normalizedTime` is exactly `1.0`? Then the integer part is 1 (indicating that the clip has been looped once and we are now in the second interation) and the floating part is 0 which means that it is the first frame of the clip. But at the same time, the `normalizedTime` value of 1.0 should mean that we are at the very last frame of the clip before it is looped.

For clips that are perfect loops, this might be no problem. But what if the clip is not a loop? How can I detect that I am now at the very last frame? Theoretically the `normalizedTime` should then be `0.99999999999999999999f`.

Is this correct? How to interpret `normalizedTime == 1.0f`?

Answer (score 2):

I found it out myself. If "Loop Time" of the clip is enabled, any normalizedTime >= 1.0 belongs to the second (or third, ...) loop. Even numbers that are very close to 1.0 like 0.9999999 belong to the second frame. That means that you can end up having the first frame of the clip when you really expect the last frame.

There seems to be no value of normalizedTime that guarantees the last frame.